# не могу установить HomeBrew, Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: консоль, macos, homebrew

```
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R vovaevdan:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
**xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
Failed during: git init -q**
```

Comment: всё же написано: or use `xcode-select --install` to install

Comment: написал 'xcode-select --install' и высветилось: 'xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates'

Comment: значит первая подсказка, что-то вроде `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`, нужно только узнать путь к Xcode.app

Comment: написал: sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app, и он написал xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app'. хотя путь к програме - /Applications/Xcode.app